# Can an Android Architecture Components ViewModel compose an object from multiple LiveData returning models?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I've been unable to create an Android Architecuture Components ViewModel that composes multiple LiveData models into one LiveData class for my Fragment to observe. I want to hide the model details from the Fragment and respond to external data changes through the individual models.

The problem is I need the ViewModel to observe the model changes but ViewModel is not a LifecycleOwner so it can't observe. Since I don't want to pass the LiveData objects through to the UI, I'm stuck.

Is this possible? Do I need to abandon LiveData for my models and resort to a different observation pattern / tool?

**Edit:** Pseudocode added. My actual classes are much more complex and lengthy. I hope my intent is understandable.

```
// OneDataModel.kt
class oneDataModel {
    val oneDataElement = ""
}

// AnotherDataModel.kt
class anotherDataModel {
    val anotherDataElement = 19
}

// OneDataRepository.kt
class OneDataRepository {
    val oneDataSet = MutableLiveData<MutableList<oneDataModel>>()

    private val dataListener = object: ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            val newChild = snapshot.getValue(oneDataModel::class.java)
            if (newChild != null) {
                oneDataSet.value?.add(newChild)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        oneDataSet.value = mutableListOf<oneDataModel>()
        OneNetworkDataTable.addListener(dataListener)
    }
}

// AnotherDataRepository.kt
class AnotherDataRepository {
    var anotherDataSet = MutableLiveData<MutableList<anotherDataModel>>()

    private val dataListener = object: ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            val newChild = snapshot.getValue(anotherDataModel::class.java)
            if (newChild != null) {
                anotherDataSet.value?.add(newChild)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        anotherDataSet.value = mutableListOf<anotherDataModel>()
        AnotherNetworkDataTable.addListener(dataListener)
    }
}

// ComposedViewModel.kt
class ComposedViewModel: ViewModel() {
    class ComposedItem {
        var dataName: String = ""   // From OneDataRepository items
        var dataValue: Int = -1     // From AnotherDataRepository items
    }
    var publishedDataSet = MutableLiveData<MutableList<ComposedItem>>()

    //***
    //*** WHAT GOES HERE? HOW DO I LISTEN TO EACH OF THE DATA REPOSITORIES AND BUILD UP COMPOSED
    //*** ITEMS FOR THE UI?
    //***
}

// MyFragment.kt
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private val composedViewModel: ComposedViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(ComposedViewModel::class.java) }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false)

        recyclerView.adapter = UIAdapter

        composedViewModel.publishedDataSet.observe(this, Observer {
            UIAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code for your question ? Hard to understand it without code.

Comment: Hope my thought is right. The things you want to do is to remove the livedata "publishedDataSet" in the statement composedViewModel.publishedDataSet.observe(...,...) and some how the fragment can have the viewmodel and it can be observe automatically and update the UI ?

Comment: Thanks, @Long Ranger, that's the approach I took on a branch since I was stuck. What I don't like about it is that my ViewModel is basically empty, just passing the LiveData repository members along. That means the Fragment and Adapter have to understand the database schema to know where to get what they need. It feels more like MVC or MVP which I don't think AAC intends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope my work satisfy your question.

I have made a sample project before and now integrate another fake livedata into this view model. [Difference of the file](https://github.com/charlesng/SampleAppArch/commit/5ff7c89d1fe04af8edae284b1f9d5435b0533b6b)

Use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html) class to wrap multi data source to one.

**FeedEntryListViewModel.java**

```
public class FeedEntryListViewModel extends ViewModel {

  //list all your live data here
  private LiveData<List<FeedEntry>> feedEntries = new MutableLiveData<>();
  private MutableLiveData<String> userId = new MutableLiveData<>();
  //show your composite model here
  private MediatorLiveData<CompositeModel> compositeModelLiveData;

  //list all your repository
  private FeedEntryRepository feedEntryDBRepository;

  /*
  The complete model to show the data
   */
  public static class CompositeModel {

    String userId = "SystemId";
    private List<FeedEntry> feedEntries = new ArrayList<>();


    public String getUserId() {
      return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
      this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<FeedEntry> getFeedEntries() {
      return feedEntries;
    }

    public void setFeedEntries(
        List<FeedEntry> feedEntries) {
      this.feedEntries = feedEntries;
    }


  }

  public FeedEntryListViewModel(
      FeedEntryRepository feedEntryDBRepository) {
    this.feedEntryDBRepository = feedEntryDBRepository;
    this.feedEntries = feedEntryDBRepository.getAll();
    this.compositeModelLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    this.compositeModelLiveData.addSource(feedEntries, data ->
    {
      CompositeModel compositeModel = compositeModelLiveData.getValue();
      compositeModel.setFeedEntries(data);
      compositeModelLiveData.postValue(compositeModel);
    });
    this.compositeModelLiveData.addSource(userId, data -> {
      CompositeModel compositeModel = compositeModelLiveData.getValue();
      compositeModel.setUserId(data);
      compositeModelLiveData.postValue(compositeModel);
    });
    //initialize the composite model to avoid NullPointerException
    this.compositeModelLiveData.postValue(new CompositeModel());
  }

  public void loadUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId.setValue(userId);
  }

  public LiveData<List<FeedEntry>> getFeedEntrys() {
    return feedEntryDBRepository.getAll();
  }

  public LiveData<CompositeModel> getCompositeEntrys() {
    return compositeModelLiveData;
  }

  public LiveData<List<FeedEntry>> insert(FeedEntry... feedEntries) {
    feedEntryDBRepository.insertAll(feedEntries);
    return feedEntryDBRepository.getAll();
  }

  public void delete(FeedEntry feedEntry) {
    feedEntryDBRepository.delete(feedEntry);
  }


  public int update(FeedEntry feedEntry) {
    return feedEntryDBRepository.update(feedEntry);
  }

}
```

In the Activity, you still can get the composite with the statement

```
viewModel.getCompositeEntrys().observe(this, entries -> {...});
```

View Model Constructor add the live data and bind to the composite live data

```
 public FeedEntryListViewModel(
      FeedEntryRepository feedEntryDBRepository) {
    this.feedEntryDBRepository = feedEntryDBRepository;
    this.feedEntries = feedEntryDBRepository.getAll();
    this.compositeModelLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    this.compositeModelLiveData.addSource(feedEntries, data ->
    {
      CompositeModel compositeModel = compositeModelLiveData.getValue();
      compositeModel.setFeedEntries(data);
      compositeModelLiveData.postValue(compositeModel);
    });
    this.compositeModelLiveData.addSource(userId, data -> {
      CompositeModel compositeModel = compositeModelLiveData.getValue();
      compositeModel.setUserId(data);
      compositeModelLiveData.postValue(compositeModel);
    });
    //initialize the composite model to avoid NullPointerException
    this.compositeModelLiveData.postValue(new CompositeModel());
  }
```

Comment: Have you run this code and seen the model data make it into the compositeModel and up to the observer? I tried similar with MediatorLiveData along the way without success. Your approach is slightly different than I recall, so I'll try again.

Comment: It's working! When I tried MediatorLiveData before, I had it wrong. The right way, as you show, is to have the models / repository publish LiveData properties and the ViewModel bring them together in a MediatorLiveData property that the Fragment can observe. Now my Fragment only sees the ViewModel and the data layer is appropriately hidden. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a different approach:

- Use reactive streams (*RxJava*) to represent your model
- Convert your RxJava Observables into LiveData using `lifecycle-reactivestreams` from the Architecture Components.

By using *RxJava* you can easily merge observables together and only expose that combination to the view using `LiveData`. I would recommend to use `LiveData` only to expose state to the view (`Fragment` or `Activity`).

I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@argenkiwi/the-model-in-mvvm-7fef986a1894) on how to do this. You might find it useful.