# join firebase model and update live data with combined results

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

HelloBelow is my database structure 
[image]

I want to first get results from post object and using "userid" from that I want to get results from Users Object. 
I want to update ViewModel with the above results that contain fields that are in both the objects 
How to achieve this ? 
I have written code to get the result from post object but how to again make call to get user object and update viewmodel and livedata object

```
  private static final DatabaseReference POST_REF =
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Post");

   private final FirebaseQueryLiveData liveData = new 
   FirebaseQueryLiveData(POST_REF);
   @NonNull
   public LiveData<DataSnapshot> getDataSnapshotLiveData() {

return liveData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to model you database to archive this, It is always good to follow best practices see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure

In this case, since you only want the Profile Pic and name I would save it directly into the object:

```
    {
    "Posts":{
        "post1":
        {
            "likes":23,
            "userId":"id",
            "user":
            {
                "imageUrl":"url", 
                "name":"Name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the tradeoff is that the image URL won’t be updated if the user node gets updated (unless you code something to update it in a Cloud Function for example)

On the other hand, you could also perform those two calls to the Firebase Realtime Database (one to get the post, and the other to get the user data):

```
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot) {
                post.setUser(userDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);)
            }
        };
        mUserReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(userListener);//only fetch data once
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

**EDIT:**

Having the user object inside the post would work using the architecture components (Just be sure to have the proper class to deserialize), on the other hand, since you are using the FirebaseQueryLiveData https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html and may want to avoid writing the user on that post node, I think you can have both ViewModels with different Database references, and once the data is fetched you could just update the post object e.g. `post.setUser(user)` with the user obtained from the other ViewModel Observer and then update the UI. You could also have a HashMap to keep track of what post needs what user, although this answer looks like a way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483213/1537389. Hope that helps

Comment: I realize now your question is specific about LiveData with ViewModel I'll try to update the post to match the stablished environment